# How to clone the "Projects" Custom Post type in Divi theme

Tags: custom-post-types, templates

My goal is to clone the functionality of "Projects" in the Divi theme by Elegant Themes. Projects is a custom post type that is a portfolio. I'd like to clone exactly all the features so that I have a second custom post type just like "Projects" that I will call "Compare".

Can I copy the code from the default 'single-project.php' since I want my custom post type to perform exactly as the project, but rename it to 'single-compare.php' and put this in my Divi child theme and it should work?

Or are there other things I need to do?

Answer (score 1):

That should be all you need to do. I would suggest creating a [child theme](https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes) if you haven't already, and put the new template files there.